# How to make a customized scroll in LazyRow Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a trello application clone in jetpack compose. In which there is a screen where all the lists in the board are displayed in a row , I have used lazyRow to implement that.
One difference I saw when scrolling the lists in the original trello app was that while scrolling the next item would stop exactly at the middle of the screen and it also doesn't skip any item even if we scroll with more speed.

Whereas in the LazyRow in my clone application the scroll behavoiur just depends on the power of our scroll.

I wanted to know if we could implement the trello like scrolling functionality in LazyRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`SnapFlingBehavior`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/a89064455056b0fa2dadc953642ccd98f41b2972:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/snapping/SnapFlingBehavior.kt;l=83) for that. You can have a look at the [`HorizontalPager`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/Pager.kt;l=108?q=HorizontalPager&sq=&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) implementation to see how it is used - it is a wrapper for `LazyRow` which is using `SnapFlingBehavior`. Depending on what exactly you need, you might be even able to simply replace your `LazyRow` with `HorizontalPager` and use different `pageSize` than the default `PageSize.Fill`.

Comment: I read the documentation and came to know that we can use the fling behavior with the lazy row as well without using HorizontalPager, thanks for your reply :)